# Get steamid64 from steamapi

Tags: c#, steam-web-api

I'm working on something for a friend at the moment, but I'm not sure how to pull data from the Steam API. How would I import the steamid's from [here](http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetFriendList/v0001/?key=AAF472F9B2494C943447F4488C912D6D&steamid=76561198254673414&relationship=friend) into an array or something of the sort?

```
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] SteamId = { };
        foreach (string sid in SteamId)
        {
            textBox1.Text = sid;
        }


    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

At the moment, i just have a blank array because i'm not sure how i'd go about getting the info from the API.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your post to include what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to make an HTTP request to that URL from within your code. Then parse the response (default format is JSON). Also, please remove your key from that link you included and get a new Steam API key.

Cheers.